# Find values in list which differ from reference list by up to N characters

Tags: python, string

I have a list like the following:

`Test = ['ASDFGH', 'QWERTYU', 'ZXCVB']`

And a reference list like this:

`Ref = ['ASDFGY', 'QWERTYI', 'ZXCAA']`

I want to extract the values from `Test` if they are N or less characters different from any one of the items in `Ref`.

For example, if N = 1, only the first two elements of Test should be output. If N = 2, all three elements fit this criteria and should be returned.

It should be noted that I am looking for same charcacter length values (ASDFGY -> ASDFG matching doesn't work for N = 1), so I want something more efficient than levensthein distance.

I have over 1000 values in ref and a couple hundred million in Test so efficiency is key.

Comment: Are you allowing *any* character position to be a mis-match? Your examples all have the mis-matches at the ends of the strings.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Yes, any character position can mismatch. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Have you tried to solve this yet? Which specific step are you stuck on?

Answer (score 1):

Using a generation expression with `sum`:

```
Test = ['ASDFGH', 'QWERTYU', 'ZXCVB']
Ref = ['ASDFGY', 'QWERTYI', 'ZXCAA']

from collections import Counter

def comparer(x, y, n):
    return (len(x) == len(y)) and (sum(i != j for i, j in zip(x, y)) <= n)

res = [a for a, b in zip(Ref, Test) if comparer(a, b, 1)]

print(res)

['ASDFGY', 'QWERTYI']
```

Comment: Does this only work for variations at the end of the sequence? Perhaps I should have been more explicit about it, but the difference can be anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 1):

The [**newer `regex` module**](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) offers a "fuzzy" match possibility:

```
import regex as re

Test = ['ASDFGH', 'QWERTYU', 'ZXCVB']
Ref = ['ASDFGY', 'QWERTYI', 'ZXCAA', 'ASDFGI', 'ASDFGX']


for item in Test:
    rx = re.compile('(' + item + '){s<=3}')
    for r in Ref:
        if rx.search(r):
            print(rf'{item} is similar to {r}')
```

This yields

```
ASDFGH is similar to ASDFGY
ASDFGH is similar to ASDFGI
ASDFGH is similar to ASDFGX
QWERTYU is similar to QWERTYI
ZXCVB is similar to ZXCAA
```

You can control it via the `{s<=3}` part which allows three or less substitutions.

---

To have pairs, you could write

```
pairs = [(origin, difference) 
        for origin in Test 
        for rx in [re.compile(rf"({origin}){{s<=3}}")]
        for difference in Ref
        if rx.search(difference)]
```

Which would yield for

```
Test = ['ASDFGH', 'QWERTYU', 'ZXCVB']
Ref = ['ASDFGY', 'QWERTYI', 'ZXCAA', 'ASDFGI', 'ASDFGX']
```

the following output:

```
[('ASDFGH', 'ASDFGY'), ('ASDFGH', 'ASDFGI'), 
 ('ASDFGH', 'ASDFGX'), ('QWERTYU', 'QWERTYI'), 
 ('ZXCVB', 'ZXCAA')]
```

Comment: Why does this not yield ZXCVB is similar to ZXCAA? You allowed for up to 3 substitutions, and this is only 2 substitutions.

Comment: @JackArnestad: Right you are. Updated, you need to put parentheses around the item, otherwise only the last char was analyzed.

Answer (score 1):

Using `difflib`

**Demo:**

```
import difflib
N = 1
Test = ['ASDFGH', 'QWERTYU', 'ZXCVB']
Ref = ['ASDFGY', 'QWERTYI', 'ZXCAA']
result = []
for i,v in zip(Test, Ref):
    c = 0
    for j,s in enumerate(difflib.ndiff(i, v)):
        if s.startswith("-"):
            c += 1
    if c <= N:
        result.append( i )
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['ASDFGH', 'QWERTYU']
```